# GME use in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, installation, gme

I have downloaded GME from spatialecology.com but I can not find a toolbar for it in ArcGIS 10.

Should I be able to use GME within ArcGIS?

If so, how do I add the extension.

If not, how do I run GME?

Answer (score 2):

[GME is a stand-alone program that can be started from the Windows Start button -- Programs -- SpatialEcology.](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/gmedownload.htm)  The program will install typically here:

C:\Program Files\SpatialEcology